# How to boot into safe mode with RDP enabled on GCP

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machines, rdp, safe-mode

Read title. I am trying to figure out how to boot into safe mode on a windows VM and still be able to connect to it via RDP (or another remote service).

Comment: Advanced boot options section of the Troubleshooting Windows VMs document appears to be explaining this [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-windows#advanced-boot-options).

Comment: Thanks @jabbson! If you'd like to enter this as an answer I'll mark it as answer and upvote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advanced boot options section of the Troubleshooting Windows VMs document appears to be explaining this [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-windows#advanced-boot-options).

Comment: Hmm, appears I don't yet have enough reputation to upvote. As soon as I do I will though. Marked as answer in the meantime :)